# Unable to use "transient-key" when generating a batch GPG key

Tags: gnupg, pgp, public-key

I'm generating a few test keys, but I can't seem to use the `%no-protection` and `%transient-key` flags. I get the following message:

```
$ cat dwight | gpg --homedir "dwight-keys" --gen-key --batch
gpg: keyring `dwight-keys/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `dwight-keys/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: Generating a key for Dwight Schrute
gpg: skipping control `%no-protection' ()
gpg: skipping control `%transient-key' ()

Not enough random bytes available.  Please do some other work to give
the OS a chance to collect more entropy! (Need 27 more bytes)
......+++++
```

The error message states the `%no-protection` and `%transient-key` controls are skipped. This you can see as the key generator is trying to pull the random bytes from `/dev/random` which [if I understand the documentation correctly](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html), `%transient-key` is supposed to prevent.

This is the config file I am using to generate the key:

```
%echo Generating a key for Dwight Schrute
%no-protection
%transient-key
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 4096
Subkey-Type: RSA
Subkey-Length: 4096
Name-Real: Dwight Schrute
Name-Email: dwight.schrute@dundermifflin.com
Creation-Date: 2005-03-24
Expire-Date: 0
%commit
%echo Key generated
```

Comment: Fun fact, [Googling the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22skipping+control+%60%25no-protection%27%22) just leads me to the source code of GPG and a single reference to the error message in an old archived 4chan thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by looking at the GnuPG [source](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/keygen.c;hb=refs/heads/master) it seems that the `%no-protection` and `%transient-key` controls were added in [`764e88d4df29204be6ea2206cf753c56ec0f5b5f`](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=commitdiff;h=764e88d4df29204be6ea2206cf753c56ec0f5b5f#patch11), which is only on the 2.1 branch, and I'm betting your GnuPG is from the 2.0 branch.

Comment: Even worse, running `gpg --version` I see I'm using `1.4.16`. I assumed the version found in the Ubuntu repositories would be a bit more up to date.

Comment: Ubuntu has both. gnupg2 for the 2.0 branch, tho you'll probably have to find a PPA for 2.1